# How to provide credentials to a service which is need to use an thirdparty service

Tags: authentication, architecture, microservices

I need some advice about architectural design or best practice approaches.
I have a service that needs some credentials for some third party services.
My Service used by a webapp which currently keeps this credentials in a DB in encrypted mode.
WebApp and MyService are going to communicate over a MessageQueue (RabbitMQ).

How can I provide my Service these credentials from web app. Or should I completely change the design and how? [image: How it looks like]

Thanks in Advance

KR
Timur

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated area, and different people have different ideas about how to do this; the problem with your design is that an attacker who can sniff the traffic between your web app and your services can get access to your keys.
You also have tight coupling between your apps and your services, as well as all the entertainment of managing credentials between dev, qa and prod environments.

Many hosting strategies include a "key management server" for this purpose - AWS has https://aws.amazon.com/kms/, for instance. I'd suggest reading up on their use cases.

Another popular solution is to store the keys in environment variables, and manage them as part of your build/deploy pipelines.

Finally some frameworks (e.g. Ruby on Rails) store these details in a credentials file, and have workflows for managing them outside the source code control processes.